# Disable poe in specific ports

Tags: networking

so I have 2 switches at work: One is a ProCurve 2810-48G and the other is a 2530-48G. Title of the question is pretty explanatory, is there a way to turn off the power to a specific port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
conf t
interface XXX
no power
end
wr mem
logout
y
```